# SonarQube stoped on loading page

Tags: sonarqube

I had installed the SonarQube 7.9.x LTS on a Linux virtual machine. When I start the Sonar it stop on loading page with spin load forever. Using "F12" on console tab, I got the error message:

```
GET http://172.29.200.143:9000/js/vendors-main.m.d184ed05.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Please, what should I do?

Comment: I would like to download the file and paste where it should be. FILE: 

"vendors-main.m.d184ed05.chunk.js" 

Location where it should be:  

"/sonarqube-7.9.1/web/js/"

Can anyone provide the file??

Answer (score 2):

You should uncomment & modify the sonar.web.context property inside sonar

Config file : `/opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties`

Example : `sonar.web.context=/sonar`

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem where the Page Load would hang forever. The solution here "Open a Firewall Port" https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-8-9-doesnt-start-its-blocked-in-loading-page-after-login/43149/21 won't apply to me as I'm running SonarQube locally via localhost:9000

### Solution

As soon as I used Chrome it worked, an old IE is *probably* unsupported now:

[image]